# Pivot multiple input parameter in SQL server?How to reduce query running time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-2008

Below query i have writing for Daily Inventory-sale for each shop in have 2millon row data for a month like that i have more then 250 shop!!
Its take longer then expected !!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getDaily]

--Declare  
          @date1 date = '2015-06-01'
              ,@date2 date = '2015-06-30'
                ,@StoreNo Nvarchar(Max)=' AND S.StoreNo IN (61,63,450,451)'


AS
BEGIN
             IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#calender') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #calender
                IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Temp
                 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv1
                 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv2
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#Stock') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Stock
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##StoreList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##StoreList
                    IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##final
                     IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##product') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##product

     Declare @sql_store nvarchar(max)
            SET @sql_store = 
                            'SELECT StoreNo,StoreName INTO ##StoreList FROM Store S WHERE StoreNo IN  (61,63,450,451)' + @StoreNo
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_store


            Declare 

                 @date_s char(10) = cast(@date1 as varchar)
                ,@date_e char(10) = cast(@date2 as varchar)
                ,@date_index date


                    create Table #calender  (Date date)
                    SET @date_index = @date1

                    WHILE @date_index<=@date2
                    BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO #calender
                    SELECT @date_index

                    SET @date_index = dateadd(day,1,@date_index)

                    IF @date_index>@date2
                    Break
                    ELSE
                    Continue
                    END


       BEGIN
                SELECT 
                             ProductNo as ProductBarCode,Date

                        INTO ##product
                                    FROM Product,#calender

                    WHERE StartUseDate <= @date_s AND EndUseDate >=@date_e and IsInUsed = 1

        END

create table #inventory (StoreNo int ,Date date, ProductBarCode varchar(14),ProductQty int )



      BEGIn

                    Select 
                                       STD.StoreNo As StoreNo
                                       ,CheckDate as Date
                                       ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                      , SUM( StocktakingQty)AS ProductQty
                            INTO ##Temp   
                                    From StockTakingDetail STD
                Inner Join
                             (Select     
                                        StoreNo
                                        ,CheckNo
                                        ,CheckDate 
                                     From StockTakingMain SM )StocktakingMain 
                                 On STD.CheckNo =StockTakingMain.CheckNo

                           group By STD.StoreNo,STD.ProductBarCode,CheckDate






                    --Insert INTO #inventory    
                                SELECT A.StoreNo ,C.[date],A.ProductBarCode,A.ProductQty

                            INTO ##inv1
                                FROM  #calender C
                                OUTER APPLY 
                                (
                                    SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM ##Temp I WHERE I.Date < C.DATE and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )   ORDER BY I.Date
                                ) A
                                OPTION (maxrecursion 0)


                    --Insert INTO #inventory    
                                SELECT B.StoreNo ,C.[date],B.ProductBarCode,B.ProductQty

                            INTO ##inv2
                                FROM  #calender C
                                OUTER APPLY 
                                (
                                    SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM ##temp I WHERE I.Date > C.DATE and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )   ORDER BY I.Date
                                ) B
                                OPTION (maxrecursion 0)


              INSERT INTO #inventory
                      Select  S.StoreNo,s.Date,s.ProductBarCode,ISNULL (sum(s.ProductQty),0) as ProductQty

                        From
                        (Select StoreNo,Date,ProductBarCode,ProductQty from ##inv1

                        Union all
                        Select StoreNo,Date,ProductBarCode,ProductQty from ##inv2
                        )S
                        WHERE StoreNo IS NOT NULL
                       GROUP BY s.StoreNo,s.Date,s.ProductBarCode

            END



       BEGIN 

            select
                 S.Date as Date,S.StoreNo As StoreNo,(S.ProductBarCode ) as ProductBarCode,sum(S.Qty) as ProductQty
        INTO #Stock
            from 
                --- sale
                (
                    select  
                                StoreNo As StoreNo,
                                PluCode as ProductBarCode,
                                cast (sum(BuyPoint/100)as int) as Qty,
                                Date as Date
                    from POS_ItemTran p  
                    where 
                            Date between  @date_s and @date_e and p.StoreNo IN(select StoreNo from ##StoreList)
                    Group by 
                            PluCode,StoreNo,Date

                union all 

                 --Transfer IN
                        select   
                                 TD.TargetStoreNo as StoreNo
                                 ,TD.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                 ,SUM(TD.AcceptQty)*(-1) as Qty
                                 ,AcceptDate as Date  
                                            from TransferDetail TD
                Inner join
                             (Select  TransferSerialNo
                             ,AcceptDate 
                                   from TransferMain )TM

                      ON TM.TransferserialNo = TD.TransferserialNo
                          where 
                                  AcceptDate between @date_s and @date_e and TargetStoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                               Group by 
                                     TargetStoreNo,TD.ProductBarcode,AcceptDate

                 union all

                 -- Transfer out
                             Select 
                                TD.TransferStoreNo as StoreNo
                                , TD.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                ,SUM(TD.TransferQty) As Qty
                                ,TransferDate as Date 
                                           from TransferDetail TD 
                 Inner Join
                            (Select TransferSerialNo
                                      ,TransferDate 
                                             from TransferMain)TMO
                              On TMO.TransferSerialNo = TD.TransferSerialNo
                         where 
                                 TransferDate between @date_s and @date_e and TransferStoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                        Group by 
                                 TD.TransferStoreNo,TD.ProductBarCode,TransferDate

                 --Loss
                UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                            StoreNo
                            ,LossProductBarCode
                            ,SUM(LossQty) as Qty,
                            LossDate as Date

                                FROM LossDetail LD
                INNER JOIN  
                    (SELECT 
                         StoreNo
                         ,LossSerialNo
                         ,LossDate  
                             FROM LossMain LM)LossMain ON LD.LossSerialNo = LossMain.LossSerialNo
                      where 
                           LossDate between @date_s and @date_e and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                    GROUP BY 
                           StoreNo,LossProductBarCode,LossDate
                Union All
                    --Buy
                     Select
                          BuyStore as StoreNo
                           ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                             ,SUM(BuyQty)*(-1)as Qty
                               ,BuyDate as Date 
                                    from BuyDetail BD
                Inner Join 
                       (Select 
                          BuySerialNo
                            ,BuyDate 
                                 from BuyMain BM) BuyMain ON BD.BuySerialNo = BuyMain.BuySerialNo
                    where  
                           BuyDate Between @date_s and @date_e and BuyStore IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                    Group BY
                           BuyDate,BuyStore,ProductBarCode,BuyDate

                Union All
                    --RCVBackDetail
                        Select 
                           RcvBackStoreNo as StoreNo
                           ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                           ,SUM(RcvBackQty)*(-1) as Qty
                           ,RcvBackDate as Date
                        from RcvBackDetail RBD
                    Inner Join
                        (SELECT RcvBackSerialNo
                                ,RcvBackDate 
                                     FROM RcvBackMain)RcvBackMain
                        ON RcvBackMain.RcvBackSerialNo = RBD.RcvBackSerialNo 
                        Where 
                             RcvBackDate Between @date_s and @date_e and RcvBackStoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                        Group By 
                              RcvBackDate,RcvBackStoreNo,ProductBarCode


                )S
                        Group by S.StoreNo,S.ProductBarCode,S.Date

                END


    Declare     @pheader nvarchar(Max),@sql_pivot nvarchar(max)

    Begin 

        SELECT   @pheader=ISNULL(@pheader,'')+'['+StoreName+'],'
                                                    FROM ##StoreList GROUP BY StoreNo,StoreName ORDER BY StoreNo
                                                    SET @pheader= LEFT(@pheader, LEN(@pheader) - 1)

                                                    SET @sql_pivot=
                                                        N'Select * from'+
                                                        '(
                                                            SELECT 

                                                                    StoreName
                                                                  ,p.Date as Date
                                                                  ,p.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                                                  ,isnull(i.productqty-(select ProductQty as runningsum from #Stock st where st.date<=i.date and st.storeno=i.storeno and st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode ),i.productqty) as ProductQty

                                                From #inventory i
                                                            LEFT JOIN Store S ON S.StoreNo = i.StoreNo 
                                                        Left JOIN #Stock st ON st.StoreNo = i.StoreNo and st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode and st.Date = i.Date
                                                        left Join ##product p ON i.ProductBarCode = p.ProductBarCode and i.Date = P.Date
                                                          --WHERE p.ProductBarCode IN (0065103700004,
                                                                --                              2017961746012)
                                                            GROUP BY 

                                                                    i.storeNo
                                                                    ,StoreName
                                                                  ,i.ProductBarCode 
                                                                   ,p.ProductBarCode
                                                                   ,p.Date
                                                                   ,i.Date
                                                                   ,i.ProductQty)p


                                                                pivot
                                                                (sum(ProductQty) for [StoreName] IN ('+ @pheader+N')
                                                                ) As Pivt order By Date,ProductBarCode'


                                        EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sql_pivot


                SET @pheader = NULL  
                SELECT   @pheader=ISNULL(@pheader,'')+'0 as ['+cast(StoreNo as varchar)+'],'
                FROM ##StoreList GROUP BY StoreNo ORDER BY StoreNo
                SET @pheader= LEFT(@pheader, LEN(@pheader) - 1)

                SET  @pheader =  ' SELECT  0 as '+''''+'         '+''''+', 0 as '+''''+'          '+''''+','+'0 as '+''''+'           '+''''+', 0 as '+''''+'            '+''''+','+@pheader
                EXECUTE sp_executesql  @pheader
  END


Drop Table #inventory
--Drop Table #calender
IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#inventory') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #inventory
IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#calender') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #calender
IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Temp
 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv1
                 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv2
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#Stock') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Stock
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##StoreList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##StoreList
                   IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##final
                    IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##product') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##product

END
```

i have kind of idea why its slow ,if add product table its taking long time !! but i dont know how to change and write the query !
  how to write another way to reduce running time and during pivot table i can able to add only one store number but i want to add more i have no idea why its not getting multiple parameter input!

if anyone can suggest or help!
Advance Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Create indexes for all large temp tables.  Just after populating them via (SELECT INTO)